# Converting mysql_result to mysqli when creating a session

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to convert a mysql script to mysqli and have hit a wall. I am trying to convert a mysql_result to mysqli however am unsure how to do this, below is my code

```
$_SESSION['num_user'] = mysql_result(mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `members` WHERE mem_emailactivated = 1"), 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as it is, there doesn't seem to be a way to fetch without prepare/execute.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($GLOBALS['___mysqli_ston'], "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count ...");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
$_SESSION['num_user'] = $count;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing things up here. You wouldn't use `mysql_result` to get the result from a query using `mysqli`. you would instead use `mysqli` to iterate through the returned array and then store this array in the `$_SESSION`.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("call getUsers()");
if($result){
     // Cycle through results
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $user_arr[] = $row;
    }

    $result->close();
}

$_SESSION['num_user'] = $user_arr;
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.